BQ25570 setting different overvoltage, battery ok and MPPT levels
I am trying to build a flexible module, using BQ25570. By the flexibility I mean that I can, using microcontroller, set different overvoltage (OV), battery ok (OK) and MPPT thresholds (MPPT), let's say 3 different levels on each. In this design, static consumption is the main concern. Since manufacturer lists typical total resistance > 10 Meg for OV, OK and MPPT networks, I would like to use as much resistance as I can. Also, manufacturer lists minimal total resistance.
However, using simple MOSFET switches to set different level looks bad, because MOSFET's have finite off-state resistance in order of some to tenth of megohms. My initial idea was to use low-power DAC's and use their signals to drive a low-power operational amplifier as a buffer, which output was weakly pulled up to the supply rail. This approach needs at least 3 DAC's, but the preferred microcontroller has only one IDAC output, and getting low-power DAC's for me is tough. Using latched relays also undesirable, because of board space.
Since there are some DAC's with current consumption < 5 μA, I am wondering, are there any options to build that flexible module, and if yes, what is the solution?

Turns out that best solution for low count of discrete levels is to use miniature bistable relays.
Pros: no additional static power loss (leakage e.g.), simple control, state is retained even if system is not powered.
Cons: only discrete levels of signal with low resolution can be obtained, many resistors for dividers networks needed if more discrete levels needed, solution size.
Also there are two reasonable solutions which has more cons. One is using MOSFETs/analog switches.
Pros: smaller solution size, analog switches with low leakage and logic-level control.
Cons: only discrete levels of signal with low resolution can be obtained, many resistors for dividers networks needed if more discrete levels needed, additional static power consumption (leakage), MOSFETs solution which using source follower connection needs additional boost converter to obtain voltage on gate higner than source on at least Vgs, state is lost when system is not powered.
Second solution is to use low-power DAC and buffer with open drain output.
Pros: flexible setting (high resolution), relatively small solution size
Cons: high additional static power consumption (DAC and additional components supply current), state is lost when system is not powered, in case of using EFM32 microcontrollers can't go lower then EM2 mode, to find out what voltage should be at the DAC output, you first need to get the voltage value at the VOC_SAMP, therefore, you need to connect the ADC input to the capacitor from which the voltage is sampled and this is highly not recommended (case of flexible setting MPPT levels).

You could use relays to short or switch the megaohm resistors.
In the picture below the resistance between the bq25570 and node A can be switched between 1 and 2 Megaohms. You may want to limit the current through the coil with R4

Keep in mind that there are some drawbacks:

holding a relay closed needs constant power
relays will switch for 10.000 cycles, keep some spare ones for replacment.


"In this design, static consumption is the main concern." I would think that would rule out the power consumption of a relay's coil?
